# Categories not showing as desired, what's wrong?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have categories like this:

[image: Categories Image]

I want to create a drop down menu for the categories, which I have successfully created. But the problem is that the child category is also shown as parent category whenever I click on the link.

See the below image:

[image]

I want `Western` category should appear only when `Apparels` category is clicked (which works perfectly fine) and it should not appear when clicked on the `Categories` link.

Category Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'parent_id'
];

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withTimestamps();
}

public function childs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

In Contoller:

```
$category = Category::where('parent_id', '!=', '0')->with('childs')->get();
```

The view:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle links-titilium" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu">
        @foreach( $category as $cat )
        <li @if($cat->childs->count()) class="dropdown-submenu" @endif>
        <a class="links-titilium" href="{{ url( '/store/category', [$cat->id, Safeurl::make($cat->name)] ) }}" @if( $cat->childs->count() ) class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" @endif>
        {{ $cat->name }}
        </a>
        @if( $cat->childs->count() )
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
                @foreach( $cat->childs as $child )
                <a href="{{url('/category', [Safeurl::make($cat->name), Safeurl::make($child->name)])}}">
                {{ $child->name }}
                </a>
                @endforeach
            </li>
        </ul>
        @endif
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: https://github.com/etrepat/baum   will solve your problem out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
$category = Category::where('parent_id', '!=', '0')->with('childs')->get();
```

as per your table rows above line will fetch all the categories. To fetch the categories with level 1 try the below line.

```
$category = Category::where('parent_id', '1')->with('childs')->get();

- Apparels
- Clothes
  -- Western
```

or to fetch the top level categories with child categories

```
$category = Category::where('parent_id', null)->with('childs')->get();

- None
  - Apparels
  - Clothes
    -- Western
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir. But this is not what I am looking for. I need to fetch all the categories including child except the `None` category. And if there is a child category, it should not show it as a parent category.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make a condition right after the first foreach loop. It has to englobe the whole li so that it does not create the element if the array is at a child's index.

```
@foreach( $category as $cat )
    @if($cat->parent_id == 1) /*this is the beginning of the if statement*/
         <li @if($cat->childs->count()) class="dropdown-submenu" @endif>
              <a class="links-titilium" href="{{ url( '/store/category', [$cat->id, Safeurl::make($cat->name)] ) }}" @if( $cat->childs->count() ) class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" @endif>
                   {{ $cat->name }}
              </a>
              @if( $cat->childs->count() )
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li>
                             @foreach( $cat->childs as $child )
                                  <a href="{{url('/category', [Safeurl::make($cat->name), Safeurl::make($child->name)])}}">
                                       {{ $child->name }}
                                  </a>
                             @endforeach
                        </li>
                   </ul>
              @endif
         </li>
    @endif /*this is the end of the if statement*/
@endforeach`
```